# No Activity found to handle https:// Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Full error is this

```
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKJmEC5ieOk }
```

No idea what's going on.  I've looked at the other S/O posts and the url looks formatted correctly, http:// is lower case, and it's present.

However, if I insert it as a string literal, instead of the url String variable it launches in the browser correctly.  Mad.  I print the url in logs and there is no weird punctuation messing it up.  Can't understand it.

This is where it throws the exception:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(String url) {

    Log.v(TAG, "launching intent: " + url);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    mIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

What am I missing?  Love some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have a leading space in front of the scheme.

`dat= https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKJmEC5ieOk` should be `dat=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKJmEC5ieOk`

Comment: Bingo, thanks CommonsWare, used a .trim() and it's working.  Yay :)